# Javascript onclick action in button with two functions

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, onclick

Why this script cannot send the value in the button with onclick action simple javascript

```
<input type="submit" onclick="(document.getElementById('act').value='delete_user')&&(document.getElementById('uid').value='1')" >
```

But this script worked

```
<input type="submit" onclick="(document.getElementById('act').value='delete_user')>
```

How make both values get work ?

Comment: does "(document.getElementById('uid').value='1')" also work on its own? incidentally aren't you missing a " just before > in the example you say worked?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please try the jsFiddle provided.

Comment: Remove brackets in onclick section. it should work

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('act').value='delete_user';document.getElementById('uid').value='1'; " >
```

If it does not, please check if there is an input with id (not name) `uid` and that the following also works.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('uid').value='1'; " >
```

Check it out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/r7tuT/3/

Answer (score 0):

You are using &&, which is used for validation purpose.

Correct code is :

```
<input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('act').value='delete_user';document.getElementById('uid').value='1'" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the **html**
`<input type="submit" onclick="my_function();">`

and add in the **javascript** part:

```
function my_function(){
    document.getElementById('act').value='delete_user';
    document.getElementById('uid').value='1';
}
```

Comment: True,but I believe this should also work
`<input type="submit" onclick="my_function1();my_function2();">` if he wants to call two functions when submit is clicked.